# disown / nohup equivalants on windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, nohup

Need to SSH into a Windows machine from Linux and then disown the batch process to be started (on Windows obviously) so that it is kept alive even after the SSH session on Linux side has ended.

Comment: Try Super User.  You'll need to tell them what SSH server you're using, because that's what controls the lifetime of the subprocesses.  (Although if you have admin access, you could use `psexec` to launch a process that runs independently of the parent shell.)

Comment: thanks for the reply Harry - none of the suggested methods can be used in my case..anyway, we have opted to circumvent Windows abyss